# Fortran choose derived type by procedure call

Tags: interface, module, fortran, polymorphism, overloading

Is there a way to make a derived type have an interface so that specific module procedures are called for a generic derived type? I may not be explaining this properly, but here's a short example code of what I'd like to do:

```
  module test_mod
  implicit none

  private
  public :: type_AB ! This is what I'd like to do...
  public :: init,apply,delete

  interface type_AB ! This is what I'd like to do...
  module type type_AB
  end interface

  interface init;    module procedure init_A;      end interface
  interface init;    module procedure init_B;      end interface
  interface apply;   module procedure apply_A;     end interface
  interface apply;   module procedure apply_B;     end interface

  type type_A
    integer :: x
  end type

  type type_B
    integer,dimension(3) :: x
  end type

  contains

  subroutine init_A(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_A),intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,intent(in) :: x
    AB%x = x
  end subroutine

  subroutine init_B(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_B),intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,dimension(3),intent(in) :: x
    AB%x = 2
  end subroutine

  subroutine apply_A(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_A),intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,intent(in) :: x
    AB%x = AB%x + x
  end subroutine

  subroutine apply_B(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_B),intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,dimension(3),intent(in) :: x
    AB%x = AB%x + x
  end subroutine

  end module
```

Where I could simply use type_AB instead of specifying type_A or type_B when test_mod is used. I know that I could just specify two objects, but they are basically the same with the exception of the rank, so it would be nice to have a sort of composition/polymorphic object, but I'd rather not embed a second derived type in one. For example:

```
 type type_AB
   type(type_A) :: A
   type(type_B) :: B
 end type
```

Because it will make the class file more messy (referencing x becomes, e.g. AB%A%x instead of just AB%x if AB is of type type_AB). If this is the only way, then I suppose I can do that but I'd like to know if there are any other options. Also, using a composition/polymorphic approach adds the annoyance of needing to deallocate anything inside type_B if type_A is being used and vice versa..

I imagine others may have asked this in a better way, but when I've looked at examples, most people seem to use a f2003 standard, which I'm a bit unfamiliar with. Any help is greatly appreciated with answering or improving the question, thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I tried implementing the type extends as suggested, but this is as far as I was able to get.

```
module type_AB_mod
implicit none
private
public :: type_AB ! This is what I'd like to do...
public :: init
interface init;    module procedure init_A;      end interface
interface init;    module procedure init_B;      end interface
type type_AB
  logical :: L
end type
type, extends(type_AB) :: type_A
  integer :: x
end type
type, extends(type_AB) :: type_B
  integer,dimension(3) :: x
end type
contains
subroutine init_A(AB,x)
  implicit none
  type(type_A),intent(inout) :: AB
  integer,intent(in) :: x
  AB%x = x
  write(*,*) 'Init A'
end subroutine
subroutine init_B(AB,x)
  implicit none
  type(type_B),intent(inout) :: AB
  integer,dimension(3),intent(in) :: x
  AB%x = 2
  write(*,*) 'Init B'
end subroutine
end module
program test
use type_AB_mod
implicit none
type(type_AB) :: AB
integer :: i
integer,dimension(3) :: j
call init(AB,i)
call init(AB,j)
end program
```

I get two errors, both of which are:

```
 There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'init'
```

Referring to `call init(AB,i)` and `call init(AB,j)`

**UPDATE 2:**

I've adjusted the example to include the provided answer:

```
  module type_AB_mod
  implicit none
  private
  public :: type_AB ! This is what I'd like to do...
  public :: init
  interface init;    module procedure init_A;      end interface
  interface init;    module procedure init_B;      end interface
  type type_AB
  end type
  type, extends(type_AB) :: type_A
    integer :: x
  end type
  type, extends(type_AB) :: type_B
    integer,dimension(3) :: x
  end type
  contains
  subroutine init_A(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_AB),allocatable,intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,intent(in) :: x
    allocate(AB, source=type_A(x=x))
    write(*,*) 'Init A'
  end subroutine
  subroutine init_B(AB,x)
    implicit none
    type(type_AB),allocatable,intent(inout) :: AB
    integer,dimension(3),intent(in) :: x
    allocate(AB, source=type_B(x=x))
    write(*,*) 'Init B'
  end subroutine
  end module
  program test
  use type_AB_mod
  implicit none
  class(type_AB),allocatable :: AB
  integer :: i
  integer,dimension(3) :: j
  call init(AB,i)
  deallocate(AB)
  call init(AB,j)
  deallocate(AB)
  end program
```

But I still get the compiler errors:

```
  allocate(AB, source=type_B(x=x))
           1          2
  Error: Type of entity at (1) is type incompatible with source-expr at (2):
  allocate(AB, source=type_A(x=x))
           1          2
  Error: Type of entity at (1) is type incompatible with source-expr at (2):
```

Comment: Aren't you just looking for types and extended-types (Fortran-speak for sub-types) ?  Make your `type_a` and `type_b` extensions of a super-type (call it `type_ab` if you like).  This article (https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm) and it's other parts provides a good introduction to Fortran's OO capabilities.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `extends type` would work, it seems that I would still have to use type_a or type_b outside of test_mod... I was hoping to only use type_ab, since the init / apply should be deterministic by the arguments being passed (they have different rank). Does that make sense?

Comment: `AB` is of type `type_AB` and your generic `init`s are for types `type_A` and `type_B`.  So there's indeed no match.  If you want to use polymorphism then that's going to require a slightly different approach from if you don't.  It isn't clear from your question that you do, though.  [If you don't, just choose the type of `AB` when you declare it, and things should work.]

Comment: I'd like to only see type_AB from outside of type_AB_mod. If I change `type(type_A),intent(inout) :: AB` and `type(type_B),intent(inout) :: AB` to `type(type_AB),intent(inout) :: AB`, then I get 2 errors saying: "'x' at (1) is not a member of the 'type_ab' structure"

Comment: For the new errors, you must use `class(type_AB), ...` in the init subroutines, rather than `type(type_AB)`.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks for that! That seems to have fixed it! As for the case when type_AB has additional components, how can I assign other items (as you suggested that this was outside the scope of the question), since I've never really seen this syntax (allocate(AB,source=type_A(x=x)))....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AB` is of type `type_AB` and your specific procedures for the generic `init` are for types `type_A` and `type_B`. So there's indeed no match.

You indicate that you wish to understand the polymorphic approach to this, so that everything is based on `type_AB` in the main program.

With polymorphism, variables have *declared* and *dynamic* type.  Variables that can be either `type_A` or `type_B` will have declared type `type_AB` and dynamic type whichever is suited at the time.

We declare such a variable to have declared type `type_AB` by

```
class(type_AB), allocatable :: AB    ! Or POINTER
```

and we can set it to have dynamic type `type_A` by

```
allocate (type_A :: AB)
```

(and `type_B` *mutatis mutandis*).

Which leads to the generic resolution.  We disambiguate on the rank of the argument `x`, still, but have both specific procedures having declared type `type_AB` (after all, you want to set the dynamic type of the variable based on the other argument, so it can't be used to disambiguate).

```
subroutine init_A(AB,x)
  class(type_AB), allocatable, intent(out) :: AB
  integer, intent(in) :: x
end subroutine

subroutine init_B(AB,x)
  class(type_AB), allocatable, intent(out) :: AB
  integer, intent(in) :: x(3)
end subroutine
```

These are not ambiguous.  All that remains is to establish the dynamic type and value of the argument `AB` in each subroutine.

For the sake of clarity, I'll assume that `type_AB` hasn't a component `L`.  You can make the necessary amendments later for that.

Using intrinsic assignment in each subroutine, like

```
 AB = type_A(x=x)
```

and

```
 AB = type_B(x=x)
```

will take care of the dynamic type and value.

However, this is not supported by all current compilers, so you have other options

```
 allocate(AB, source=type_A(x=x))
```

or

```
 allocate(type_A :: AB)
 ! ... setting the component AB%x is not trivial, but outside scope of answer
```

After the call to the appropriate specific subroutine the dynamic type of `AB` in the program is as expected.

It's using the constructors for `type_A` and `type_B` above where the simplification of removing the component `L` is used.  This is where attention should be paid in the more general case.

Finally, where I say "either `type_A` or `type_B`", a variable with declared type `type_AB` could also have dynamic type `type_AB`.  Making this an abstract type removes that possibility.

Comment: I'm not able to make a working example with what you've explained. I will update what I'm using

Comment: Yes, I thought that putting the complete example would make the answer somewhat untidy/overbearing (and piecing together would be educational).  In short, change: the declaration in the main program; the declarations of the now-polymorphic dummy arguments; the assignment in the subroutines (if using gfortran, then use the allocation with source)..

Comment: It seems that you've answered my question, so I'll accept it. But it also seems that this approach is useless since I can't easily access `x` inside init_B. I think my final resolution will be to just have two separate but similar classes.

Comment: You can access `AB%x` within `init_B` using a `select type` construct.  I don't know whether you consider that not easily - but I agree that it's messy.  In general, though, when you later use these dynamic types you will use `class(type_B)` etc for those procedures acting on the array component.  The difference with this initialization routine is that you don't know ahead of time which varient you end up with.  That said, you could rewrite in such a way that, say, `AB` is set to the appropriate dynamic type and then allow the generic resolution to do its part.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, it seems a bit awkward.. I'm not sure if it's worth it.. Thanks again for your clarification!